# How can I make this web site component more legible, easier to read?

Tags: website-design, css

I have a page with weather, and I cannot figure out how to make these cells for daily weather more ... legible, I guess is the best word. Maybe "easier to read" or "better" in general.

I want to keep the page background and cell background the colors they are now, but I would like the day of the week and temperatures easier to read; as you can see, they are not easy to read. I would also like to keep the same scheme - red for high temperatures and blue for low temperatures - but they do not have to be the exact colors I have here.

My CSS:

```
html, body {
    background-color: #121212;
    color: #efefef;
    font-family: "OCR", "Courier New", "Courier", monospace;
}

.weatherCell {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin: 0 10px;
    background-color: #efefef44;
    color: #efefef;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 0.75em;
    font-weight: 700;
    border: 1px solid #DFDFDF66;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000;
}
```

[image: Weather Cell - Before]

---

**EDIT:**

Here is what this now looks like after some help from @JanusBahsJacquet:

[image: Weather Cell - After]

Comment: You could start off by not using an OCR font. OCR fonts are meant to be read by _computers_, not humans – they’re more or less inherently difficult to read (not to mean not very nice to look at). Yours seems to be quite squished as well. And if you want blue and red on a dark grey background, you’ll have to make them lighter, because dark on dark doesn’t work. And why _is_ the background such a dark grey, incidentally? It looks like it means clouds and thunderstorms., which is not what the yellow circle and the temperatures indicate…

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I like the OCR font, it pleases me. the background is dark because the page has a dark theme. Do you mean make the red and blue lighter? like `#FA8072` and `#ADD8E6`?

Comment: Yes, the red and blue need to be lighter. You need contrast from the dark grey. The black text shadow on a dark background isn’t helping either. And while the OCR font may please you, it’s not very legible, especially not when kerned so tightly.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet So, yes ... using a lighter red and blue definitely made things better. It's funny you mentioned the letter spacing as I used `letter-spacing: 0.25em` and everything looks SO much better. I thought since the cell background was light (`#efefef44`), that making the red and blue lighter wouldn't help, but it did. I'm really bad a color, style, and design in general. Thank you!

Comment: Note that `#efefef44` is a _transparent_ light colour, so the colour below will shine through. Since it’s sitting on top of an almost completely black background here, the end result ends up being a very dark colour, not a light one – it lightens the black, but only a bit.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I put a new image in my post for what it looks like now with your suggested changes. Thanks you, again.

Comment: Change the font. Even if *you* like it, it's not suitable for *visitors*.

Comment: @Scott It's really just a page for me. I don't expect many, if any, visitors.